# Access parent class variables from nested class

Tags: class, oop, system-verilog

I want to access the variables width/height/size from the nested class, putting **static** infront of them works, but is there another way?

```
class random_messages; 

    int                 max_x;
    int                 max_y;
    rand int            width; 
    rand int            height;
    rand int            size; 

    class rand_x;
        randc int  loc_x;        
        constraint sizes {
            loc_x  < width / 2**(size+3); //accessing here
            loc_x  > 0;
        }        
    endclass

endlcass
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't make the confusion of thinking that just because you define class `rand_x` inside the class `random_messages`, it automatically means that an object of the nested class gets instantiated inside an object of the wrapper class. Declaring a nested class only changes the scope where it is defined.

In your case, if you want to access variables of the parent object, you'll have to do the following:

(in the nested class) Declare a handle to the parent and take the parent in as a constructor parameter:

```
class rand_x;
  // ...

  protected random_messages m_parent;

  function new(random_messages parent);
    m_parent = parent;
  endfunction
endclass
```

(in the outer class) Declare an instance of the inner class and pass yourself as its parent:

```
class random_messages;
  // ...

  rand rand_x x;

  function new();
    x = new(this);
  endfunction
endclass
```

Comment: Note that randomization doesn't work as you might expect it, but that's a different question altogether.

Comment: Ah i see, very nice answer, nesting the class doesn't actually create any oop link, just scoping. I'm aware that calling randomize() on the outer class won't affect the inner class, which is fine by me.

Comment: is it best to say "ref this" to pass by reference and avoid copying everything? or is "this" a reference anyway?

Comment: @HDheLl `this` is a reference. There's no copying of objects when passing them around in SystemVerilog.

Comment: would passing "this.width" or "this.height" also be a reference? last question :P

Comment: @HDheLl unfortunately not. SV doesn't have references per se. Everything is pass by value. But the value of an object is the reference to that object (funky, right?). Scalar types are passed by value (i.e. a copy is passed). The semantics of passing argument in SV are similar to Java (if you know that).